# Sending a local variable to a here document, to be executed through SSH connection

Tags: unix, ssh

```
            cyber_ver="abc"
    ssh ${SSH_USER}@${server} << EOF
    mkdir ${CYBER_VER}
    EOF
```

The cyber_ver is a local variable , so not getting resolved inside the EOF block. How to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

It is not because it is in the Here Document block, but because of different case. Shell variables are **case sensitive**!

```
cyber_ver="abc"
ssh ${SSH_USER}@${server} << EOF
mkdir ${cyber_ver}
EOF
```

will do the job.